# Computation of a node value based on direct neighbors in igraph

Tags: igraph, nearest-neighbor

I am newbie in igraph. I am trying to compute hybrid centrality (eg: hybrid degree centrality of a node (v) is the total sum of degree centrality of all its direct neighbor). I have around 1500 nodes, so how can I compute the hybrid centrality in igraph?

Comment: Are you using igraph from C, R or Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, use the `neighbors()` function to get the adjacent vertices of the node, and then index your pre-calculated degree vector with it.